# Prepend line number to string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file in the following format:

```
"This is record #1"
"This is record #2"
"This is record #3"
```

I need the output in the following format:

```
Line number (1) --\t-- "This is Record # 1"
2-- \t-- "This is Record # 2"
3-- \t-- "This is Record # 3"
```

Current code:

```
f = open("C:\input.txt","r")
write_file = open("C:\output.txt","r+")
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    write_file.write(line)
    if not line : break
write_file.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: By the way, that would be _prepending_ the line number.

Comment: I apologize for framing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try traversing your file this way:

```
f = open('workfile', 'r')
for num,line in enumerate(f):
    print(num+" "+line)
```

Comment: This starts the count at 0, not 1. Give `enumerate()` a second argument: `enumerate(f, 1)` to start at 1.

Comment: I modified the code based on your answer and all the suggestions as below :    for num,line in enumerate(f,1):
    write_file.write(str(num) +"\t" + line). Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was pretty close to the target:

```
# open the file for reading
f = open("C:\input.txt","r")

# and a file for writing
write_file = open("C:\output.txt","r+")

for i, line in enumerate(f):
    line = f.readline()
    mod_line = "%s-- \t-- %s" % (i, line)  # 1-- \t-- "This is Record # 1"
    write_file.write(mod_line)

write_file.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I would love to but whenever I try to do that it says atleast 15 reputation required . Maybe since I am new. Thanks again.